# Insert multiple rows while inheriting cell styles

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an XLSX file which I want to use as a minimum template to be expanded and filled with user data using openpyxl. With 'minimum' I mean that I want to define just one or two rows within the XLSX template in the way that I later insert further rows while keeping the format / style of the rows from the template.

**Example**

```
   |    A     |    B     |    C     |    D
---+----------+----------+----------+-----...
   |          |          |          |

...

---+----------+----------+----------+-----...
   |          |          |          |
4  |          |          |          |
   |          |          |          |
---+----------+----------+----------+-----...
   |          |          |          |
5  | TEMPLATE | TEMPLATE | TEMPLATE | TEMPLATE
   |          |          |          |
---+----------+----------+----------+-----...
   |          |          |          |
6  | TEMPLATE | TEMPLATE | TEMPLATE | TEMPLATE
   |          |          |          |
---+----------+----------+----------+-----...
   |          |          |          |
7  |          |          |          |
   |          |          |          |
---+----------+----------+----------+-----...
   |          |          |          |
...
```

Now, within the template XLSX file (see example above), the rows 5 and 6 are specifically formatted regarding font, font size, border style, foreground color, vertical adjustment, ... as well as their row heights, (not standard or automatic but about `35,09` to hold about 3 lines of text).

Using openpyxl I read in the example XLSX file and then I use a Python loop to

- insert a new row at "row 6" which should result in a new row between row 5 and 6 and should be my "**new** row 6" when doing further adjustments.
- using another loop to go through each cell of the new row and copy the formats / styles from the "**former** row 6" (or even "row 5") into the new "**new** row 6"
- adjusting row height of my "**new** row 6" to be like the one of the "**former** row 6" (or even "row 5").

Here is the code:

```py
import copy

# with "ws" being the pointer to the current worksheet

# set column span
max_cols = ws.max_column

# apply for desired number of rows
for _iRow in range(10):

    # create new row
    ws.insert_rows(6)

    # set format of entire row
    for _iCol in range(1, max_cols +1):

        # cell styles
        ws.cell(6, _iCol).font = copy.copy(ws.cell(7, _iCol).font)
        ws.cell(6, _iCol).fill = copy.copy(ws.cell(7, _iCol).fill)
        ws.cell(6, _iCol).border = copy.copy(ws.cell(7, _iCol).border)
        ws.cell(6, _iCol).alignment = copy.copy(ws.cell(7, _iCol).alignment)

    # column dimensions
    ws.row_dimensions[6].height = ws.row_dimensions[5].height
```

While the single cell formats / styles get transferred into the new rows, correctly, the `row height` does only for the first new row. all further rows seem to be set to "automatic" row height and not to the one of the former inserted row.

Is this a known effect? Does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: This is just the way it works: your code will have to manage any relevant changes.

Comment: Hi @CharlieClark. this is what I intended. but when adjusting the HEIGHT in rows (or the WIDTH when dealing with columns) as shown in the last code row, somehow the adjustment does not show within the resulting XLSX. so I thought there might be something going on internally within openpyxl which would block changes when done within a fast loop?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and came up with that function which inserts a number of  rows under the "pointer" row and copies the style from each cell in that row to the newly inserted rows.

```
import openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet as _sheet
from copy import copy

def insertRowsFormat(rowP: int, number: int, sheet: _sheet.Worksheet):
    # insert rows right under the pointer row to keep same index
    sheet.insert_rows(rowP + 1, number)
    # copy style cell by cell using the reference cell at the top of the column
    for j in range(1, sheet.max_column):
        refCell =  sheet.cell(rowP, j)
        for i in range(rowP, rowP + number + 1):
            sheet.cell(i, j).font = copy(refCell.font)
            sheet.cell(i, j).border = copy(refCell.border)
            sheet.cell(i, j).fill = copy(refCell.fill)
            sheet.cell(i, j).number_format = copy(refCell.number_format)
            sheet.cell(i, j).protection = copy(refCell.protection)
            sheet.cell(i, j).alignment = copy(refCell.alignment)enter code here
```

I hope this can help someone.